# Get deepest tree nodes for branches by given parent ids

Tags: php, tree

Say I have this tree of ids/categories:

```
1
    2
    3
        4
    5
6
    7
        8
        9
10
    11
        12
            13
            14
```

I need a function to return all leaves (end nodes) based in the input ids.
But only nodes from the deepest ids given in each branch.

I'm not sure how to explain it, so here a few examples:

```
f([1])      returns [2,4,5]
f([1,2])    returns [2]
f([1,3])    returns [4]
f([1,2,3])  returns [2,4]
f([3])      returns [4]
f([4])      returns [4]
f[1,6])     returns [2,4,5,8,9]
f[11])      returns [13, 14]
f[10])      returns [13, 14]
```

The tree I'm working with are structured like this:

```
array(
    [category] => Object(Category)
    [children] => array(
        array(
            [category] => Object(Category)
            [children] => array(
                ...
            )
            [category] => Object(Category)
            [children] => array(
                ...
            )
    )
```

I also have the flat array available if that makes this easier:

```
array(
    array(id, parent_id),
    array(id, parent_id),
    etc..
)
```

After hours or searching and hair-tearing, I'm not even sure if this makes sense. How can I do this?

**Update**
As per comment; here are some code ready for copy/paste, with test cases.
As you can see, it fails on tests [4] and [10].

```
/*
Test data (tree):
0
    1
        2
        3
            4
        5
    6
        7
            8
            9
    10
        11
            12
                13
                14

Test cases:
f([1])      returns [2,4,5]
f([1,2])    returns [2]
f([1,3])    returns [4]
f([1,2,3])  returns [2,4]
f([3])      returns [4]
f([4])      returns [4]
f([1,6])    returns [2,4,5,8,9]
f([11])     returns [13, 14]
f([10])     returns [13, 14]

*/

$test[] = array('in'=>[1],      'out' => [2,4,5]);
$test[] = array('in'=>[1,2],    'out' => [2]);
$test[] = array('in'=>[1,3],    'out' => [4]);
$test[] = array('in'=>[1,2,3],  'out' => [2,4]);
$test[] = array('in'=>[1,2,5],  'out' => [2,5]);
$test[] = array('in'=>[3],      'out' => [4]);
$test[] = array('in'=>[4],      'out' => [4]);
$test[] = array('in'=>[1,6],    'out' => [2,4,5,8,9]);
$test[] = array('in'=>[11],     'out' => [13, 14]);
$test[] = array('in'=>[10],     'out' => [13, 14]);

echo '<pre>';
foreach($test as $t) {
    echo 'input: ' . implode(',',$t['in']) .' '.PHP_EOL;
    $r = f($t['in']);
    echo 'output: ' . implode(',',$r) .' ';
    if($r == $t['out']) {
        echo '(ok)';
    }
    else {
        echo '(TEST FAIL)'.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'got: ' . implode(',',$r) .' '.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'expected: ' . implode(',',$t['out']) .' ';
    }
    echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
}




function f($ids) {
    $nodes = getEndNodes(getTree(), $ids);
    return array_map(function($a){return $a['id'];},$nodes);    
}

function getEndNodes($tree, $ids, $force=false) {
    $end_nodes = array();
    foreach($tree as $el) {

        if(!empty($el['children'])) {

            // if given ids is in some of these children, search only those
            $children = array();
            foreach($el['children'] as $child) {
                if(in_array($child['element']['id'], $ids)) { $children[] = $child; }
            }
            // if no children in ids, search all (normal search)
            if(!empty($children)) {
                $end_nodes = array_merge($end_nodes, getEndNodes($children, $ids));
            }
            // if this element is in the given ids, force search
            elseif(in_array($el['element']['id'], $ids)) {
                $end_nodes = array_merge($end_nodes, getEndNodes($el['children'], $ids, true));
            }
            // if this is a force search
            elseif($force) {
                $end_nodes = array_merge($end_nodes, getEndNodes($el['children'], $ids));
            }
            else {
                // ??
            }
        }
        else {
            $end_nodes[] = $el['element'];
        }

    }
    return $end_nodes;
}


function getList() {
    $list = array(
        array('id'=>1,'parent_id'=>0),
        array('id'=>2,'parent_id'=>1),
        array('id'=>3,'parent_id'=>1),
        array('id'=>4,'parent_id'=>3),
        array('id'=>5,'parent_id'=>1),
        array('id'=>6,'parent_id'=>0),
        array('id'=>7,'parent_id'=>6),
        array('id'=>8,'parent_id'=>7),
        array('id'=>9,'parent_id'=>7),
        array('id'=>10,'parent_id'=>0),
        array('id'=>11,'parent_id'=>10),
        array('id'=>12,'parent_id'=>11),
        array('id'=>13,'parent_id'=>12),
        array('id'=>14,'parent_id'=>12),
    );
    return $list;
}

function getTree() {
    $hash = array();
    $list = getList();
    foreach($list as $el) {
        $hash[$el['id']] = array('element' => $el);
    }
    foreach($hash as $id => &$node) {
        if ($parent_id = $node['element']['parent_id']) {
            $hash[$parent_id]['children'][] =& $node;
        }
        else {
            $tree[] =& $node;
        }
    }
    unset($node, $hash);
    return $tree;
}
```

**Output**

```
input: 1 
output: 2,4,5 (ok)

input: 1,2 
output: 2 (ok)

input: 1,3 
output: 4 (ok)

input: 1,2,3 
output: 2,4 (ok)

input: 1,2,5 
output: 2,5 (ok)

input: 3 
output: 4 (ok)

input: 4 
output:  (TEST FAIL)
got:  
expected: 4 

input: 1,6 
output: 2,4,5,8,9 (ok)

input: 11 
output: 13,14 (ok)

input: 10 
output:  (TEST FAIL)
got:  
expected: 13,14
```

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard Added my test code.

Answer (score 0):

After one more day I think I got it, it's not beautiful, but it works as far as I can tell. If anyone needs this:

```
<?php

/*
Test data (tree) (0 is fictional) :
0
    1
        2
        3
            4
        5
    6
        7
            8
            9
    10
        11
            12
                13
                14
    15
    16
        17

*/

$tests = [
    ['in'=>[1],       'out' => [2,4,5]],
    ['in'=>[1,2],     'out' => [2]],
    ['in'=>[1,3],     'out' => [4]],
    ['in'=>[1,2,3],   'out' => [2,4]],
    ['in'=>[1,2,5],   'out' => [2,5]],
    ['in'=>[3],       'out' => [4]],
    ['in'=>[4],       'out' => [4]],
    ['in'=>[1,6],     'out' => [2,4,5,8,9]],
    ['in'=>[11],      'out' => [13,14]],
    ['in'=>[10],      'out' => [13,14]],
    ['in'=>[1,6,13],  'out' => [2,4,5,8,9,13]],
    ['in'=>[8,12,6],  'out' => [8,13,14]],
    ['in'=>[5],       'out' => [5]],
    ['in'=>[0],       'out' => []],
    ['in'=>[15],      'out' => [15]],
    ['in'=>[16],      'out' => [17]],
    ['in'=>[15,16],   'out' => [15,17]],
    ['in'=>[999],     'out' => []],
];

foreach($tests as $t) {
    echo 'input: ' . implode(',',$t['in']) .' '.PHP_EOL;
    $r = f($t['in']);
    echo 'output: ' . implode(',',$r) .' ';
    if($r == $t['out']) {
        echo '(ok)';
    }
    else {
        echo '(TEST FAIL)'.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'got: ' . implode(',',$r) .' '.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'expected: ' . implode(',',$t['out']) .' ';
    }
    echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
}

function f($ids) {
    $nodes = getEndNodes($ids, getTree());
    return array_map(function($a){return $a['id'];},$nodes);
}

function getEndNodes(array $ids, $tree=false, $force=false, $skip=false) {

    if(!$ids)   throw new Exception("No ids given");
    if(!$tree)  throw new Exception("No tree given");

    $end_nodes = array();
    foreach($tree as $el) {

        if(!empty($el['children'])) {

            // If given ids is in some of these children, search only those to skip their siblings.
            $children = array();
            foreach($el['children'] as $child) {
                if(in_array($child['element']['id'], $ids)) { $children[] = $child; }
            }
            if(!empty($children)) {
                $end_nodes = array_merge($end_nodes, getEndNodes($ids, $children));
            }
            // If the current element is in the input ids, force search down this tree. This will get end nodes in deep branches.
            elseif(in_array($el['element']['id'], $ids) || $force === true) {
                $end_nodes = array_merge($end_nodes, getEndNodes($ids, $el['children'], true));
            }
            // If nothing else; continue normal search, but only add input ids, not parents. The force will find them.
            else {
                $end_nodes = array_merge($end_nodes, getEndNodes($ids, $el['children'], false, true));
            }
        }
        else {
            if(!$skip && ($el['element']['parent_id'] != 0)) {
                $end_nodes[] = $el['element'];
            }
            elseif (in_array($el['element']['id'], $ids) && $el['element']['parent_id'] == 0) {
                $end_nodes[] = $el['element'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $end_nodes;
}


function getList() {
    return [
        ['id'=>1,'parent_id'=>0],
        ['id'=>2,'parent_id'=>1],
        ['id'=>3,'parent_id'=>1],
        ['id'=>4,'parent_id'=>3],
        ['id'=>5,'parent_id'=>1],
        ['id'=>6,'parent_id'=>0],
        ['id'=>7,'parent_id'=>6],
        ['id'=>8,'parent_id'=>7],
        ['id'=>9,'parent_id'=>7],
        ['id'=>10,'parent_id'=>0],
        ['id'=>11,'parent_id'=>10],
        ['id'=>12,'parent_id'=>11],
        ['id'=>13,'parent_id'=>12],
        ['id'=>14,'parent_id'=>12],
        ['id'=>15,'parent_id'=>0],
        ['id'=>16,'parent_id'=>0],
        ['id'=>17,'parent_id'=>16],
    ];
}

function getTree() {
    $hash = array();
    $list = getList();
    foreach($list as $el) {
        $hash[$el['id']] = array('element' => $el);
    }
    foreach($hash as $id => &$node) {
        if ($parent_id = $node['element']['parent_id']) {
            $hash[$parent_id]['children'][] =& $node;
        }
        else {
            $tree[] =& $node;
        }
    }
    unset($node, $hash);
    return $tree;
}
```

**Output**

```
input: 1
output: 2,4,5 (ok)

input: 1,2
output: 2 (ok)

input: 1,3
output: 4 (ok)

input: 1,2,3
output: 2,4 (ok)

input: 1,2,5
output: 2,5 (ok)

input: 3
output: 4 (ok)

input: 4
output: 4 (ok)

input: 1,6
output: 2,4,5,8,9 (ok)

input: 11
output: 13,14 (ok)

input: 10
output: 13,14 (ok)

input: 1,6,13
output: 2,4,5,8,9,13 (ok)

input: 8,12,6
output: 8,13,14 (ok)

input: 5
output: 5 (ok)

input: 0
output:  (ok)

input: 15
output: 15 (ok)

input: 16
output: 17 (ok)

input: 15,16
output: 15,17 (ok)

input: 999
output:  (ok)
```